# Отображение элемента поверх слайдера

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, fullpage

Пытаюсь сверстать сайт с помощью плагина [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            anchors:['s1','s2','s3'],
            slidesNavigation: true,
        });
    });
```

То, что есть на данный момент - [Demo](http://codepen.io/YVW/full/PPgNxZ/).
Проблема: Слово 'Works' на втором экране не всегда отображается поверх слайдера, а появляется с задержкой. Т.е. загружается страница слайдера, а уже потом отображается слово.
Как сделать так чтобы слово было постоянно поверх слайдера?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в стилях для `#works` поставить большее значение свойства `z-index:`

Comment: это не помогает